# Ошибка PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, парсер

Был скрипт парсер, подгружал посты со стороннего сайта. Все работало пока не перехал на другой хостинг. (Версия PHP везде одинаковая 7.0.)
Парсер работает но под половиной постов выскакивает это сообщение

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/u0000000/data/www/test.ru/fars.php on line 83

И остается пустым (Без информации) поле `first_name`. Хотя информация есть на стороннем сайте. Скажите в чем может быть проблема?

Часть кода с 80 строки:

```
function user($id){  

$url = 'https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_ids='.$id.'&version=5.73&fields=city,photo_100&access_token=asdfasdf';
$result = file_get_contents ($url);
$b = json_decode($result, true);

    $result = file_get_contents ($url);
    $b = json_decode($result, true);
    // Перебирает массив засовывает в переменную value.
    foreach($b['response'] as $value) : 
    endforeach;

    $first_name = $value['first_name'];
    $avatar = $value['photo_100'];
    // Достает город.
    if ($value['city'] == 113) { 
    $city = 'Москва';
    }elseif ($value['city'] == 4433) {
    $city = 'СПБ';
    }elseif ($value['city'] == 889) {
    $city = 'Воронеж';
    } else {
    $city = 'Город не определен';
    }
    //возвращает ответ из переменной $b
    return compact('first_name','city','avatar'); 
    }
```

Comment: вы массив перебирает что ли в цикле, чтобы добраться до последнего элемента? `$value = end($b['response'])`  не проще? зы: посмотрите, что у вас возвращается по ссылке, убедитесь что там валидный json и в нем есть поле `response`, которое есть массив. и конструкцию c if-elseif замените на switch или массив значений.

Comment: Вы *правда* хотите спросить у нас здесь, что лежит в вашей переменной $b['response']?

Comment: Немного подправил описание. Перебираю массив в функции user.

Comment: @teran response возвращается полным. Половина постов на выходе получаются полноценными. Другая часть без имени "first_name" с данной ошибкой.

Comment: у вас в тексте ошибки черным по белому написано, что в `foreach` передан не массив. так что без разницы, что там в `first_name`. ошибка раньше

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не много переделал Ваш код, на локальном сервере все работает

```
function user($id){
  $id = ;
  $token = '';
  $v = '5.80';
  $request = [
    'user_ids' => $id,
    'fields' => 'city,photo_100',
    'access_token' => $token,
    'v' => $v
  ];
  $rez = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?'.http_build_query($request)));
  if($rez->response) {
    foreach ($rez->response as $res) {
      $first_name = ($res->first_name) ?: '';
      $avatar = ($res->photo_100) ?: '';
      $city = ($res->city->id) ?: '';
    }
  }
  return compact('first_name','city','avatar'); 
}
```